# How to write to .csv so that "NA" missing values are read by SPSS as missing not as string

Tags: r, spss

I need to know how to read a .csv file with a lot of missing values created in R into SPSS such that those missing values are read as missing (`.` in SPSS) not as a string reading `NA`.

There are a lot of variables each with a lot of entries, and most of those entries are NA, so I don't have time to go through all the variables recoding each one-by-one from "NA" into "SYSMISS".

Does anyone have any ideas

I have tried

```
write.csv(df, "file.csv", na = ".")
```

but SPSS just reads this as a string, not as a missing value.

Comment: check out the haven package

Comment: try `foreign::write.foreign(yourData, datafile="file.csv", package="SPSS")`

Comment: thanks for the tip @G. Grothendieck `write_sav(df, "file.csv")` got it done. I've used haven for reading SPSS files into r but not the other way around. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing the file differently, you can leave as is. After reading the file into SPSS, with the problematic variables turned into strings with NA values, use:

```
alter type var1 to var250 (f8.2).
```

This will change these variables back into numbers, turning all the NA values into missing values.
(Note 1: use `to` only for groups of consecutive variables, e.g `var1 to var12 var14 var18 var20 to var30`. Note 2: replace `f8.2` with the number format you need)